# How to save the logs in the local storage of json format using winston library in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

It is possible to save the Winston logs in the local Storage using Node Js.
Please provide sample instance.

Comment: Yes, its possible.

Comment: Looks like you need custom transport. I recommend you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-transport

Comment: Can i get sample instance of custom Winston-transports for saving the logs  in the local storage